# Why is this collision detection method not hitting all objects?

Tags: c#, xna

I am currently developing a Game where the player can shoot bullets to destroy asteroids.

At the moment, this code for collision detection is hitting 1 or 2 asteroids, but not all that appear on screen.
I think there is a flaw in the following code, but I'm not sure where.

```cs
public void CollisionDetection()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ship.bullets.Count; i++)
    {
        Rectangle shipRectangle = new Rectangle((int)ship.ShipPosition.X, (int)ship.ShipPosition.Y,
        shipTexture.Width, shipTexture.Height);

        for (j = 0; j < asteroidPositions.Count; j++)
        {
            asteroidRectangle = new Rectangle((int)asteroidPositions[j].X, (int)asteroidPositions[j].Y,
            asteroidTexture.Width, asteroidTexture.Height);

            Vector2 position1 = asteroidPositions[j];
            Vector2 position2 = ship.bullets[i];

            float Cathetus1 = Math.Abs(position1.X - position2.X);
            float Cathetus2 = Math.Abs(position1.Y - position2.Y);

            Cathetus1 *= Cathetus1;
            Cathetus2 *= Cathetus2;

            distance = (float)Math.Sqrt(Cathetus1 + Cathetus2);

            if ((int)distance < asteroidTexture.Width)
            {
                score += 20;
                asteroidPositions.RemoveAt(j);
                j--;
            }
        }
        if (shipRectangle.Intersects(asteroidRectangle))
        {
            lives--;
            asteroidPositions.RemoveAt(j);
        }

        if (lives == 0)
            Exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: suggest you rename position1 into asteoridPosition and position2 into shipPosition. Just for better readability…

Comment: What is the j-- for after the removal of the asteroid?

Answer (score 1):

I think you got some of the code wrong. You just should separate the X and Y axis during distance comparison, if the Y distance is smaller than the width *and* the X distance is smaller than the height than there is a collision.

I assume the position is the middle of the object otherwise the algorithm would be far more complicated. I also assume the bullet has virtually no size and that the x.axis is the width and the y.axis is the height.
Without seeing the rest of the code its hard to tell ;-)

My suggestion:

```cs
Vector2 asteroidPosition = asteroidPositions[j];
Vector2 shipPosotion = ship.bullets[i];

float distanceX = Math.Abs(asteroidPosition.X - shipPosotion.X);
float distanceY = Math.Abs(asteroidPosition.Y - shipPosotion.Y);

if ((int)distanceX < asteroidTexture.Width and (int)distanceY < asteroidTexture.Height )
{
    score += 20;
    asteroidPositions.RemoveAt(j);
    j--;
}
```

This code is not tested at all, i even don't have a clue which language this actually is. So just take it as inspiration. Hope it will work out.

P.S.: If you are interested I could mail you the source code of some asteroid shooting game I did a while ago to study it…

Comment: It's Xna, so C#... I'm actually using similar code from other game tutorial

Comment: Maybe your collision code is'nt wrong at all if you are handling with round objects. Maybe the problem lies within the RemoveAt() method of the asteroidPositions object.

Comment: Well, the bullet sometimes goes "over" asteroids, about once every so often it'll properly hit and remove an asteroid...